# Is it possible to use SIM card to mutual authentication on access to a secure web server with Android?

Tags: android, ssl, sim-card, mutual-authentication

My intention is to use Android (browser) to mutual authenticate on a web server. For that would be nice if the Public Cert from the SIM card could be use and the signing operation from the SIM card with PIN.

Android is not the priority, Symbian or other hypothesis are to be considered, since they allow the usage i'm asking for.

Comment: So far, and after talking to some guys from Portugal Telecom seams that is not possible, since google don't allow the "emulation" of the simcard to a virtual card that could be used to do what i meant.