# login to web-app with SIM card

Tags: authentication, sim-card

I would like to create a mobile app that connects securely to the web server. In order to avoid having to rely on user/password authentication, I would like to authenticate the devices with their SIM card.

I know there is a certificate on the SIM card and I have found EAP authentication. But all the articles are about WiFi access points.

Is it possible to send the EAP request from a web-app? If yes how?

thank you for your help

he says its not possible: [Is it possible to use SIM card to mutual authentication on access to a secure web server with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026828/is-it-possible-to-use-sim-card-to-mutual-authentication-on-access-to-a-secure-we) but I can't believe that.

Comment: I looked around and it appears that Android does not allow interaction with the SIM card: http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html#sim-card-access

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar solution and a good starting point is a project run by Telenor for authenticating applications using EAP some years ago. Here's the [link](http://projectliberty.org/liberty/content/download/816/5823/file/Telnor_SIM_Strong_Auth_LAP_COT_Dr_Do_van_Thanh.pdf).